# Unable to print awk'ed datum in bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, csv-simple, word-processing

I am dumping datum into a csv file (my_datum_file.csv). The [contents](http://www.codeshare.io/vnkkQ) are all comma seperated, and I want to find the *last* instance of the 4th parameter (i.e. the last instance of datum regarding MX3, TMX, MSV, etc. where printed). The 5th parameter is a 'subclass' of the 4th parameter (ie TMX has 098 and 001). It is also important that the 7th parameter be "status" as opposed to "SVlts". **Q:** I want the 10th value (which is a period of time in minutes) to convert to hours. I would like to print this value out.

So from the terminal I wrote:

```
$ cat /home/ed/start_up_job/my_datum_file.csv | awk -F, '( $4 == "TMX" ) && ( $5 == "098" ) && ( $7 == "status" ) {print $10/60}' | tail -1`'
```

The end result is 1022.25 hours, which is great;

I've embedded this into generic little bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

machine_ID="$1"
machine_number="$2"

echo "$1 $2 hours is `awk -F, -v MID="$machine_id" -v MNR="$machine_number" '( $4 == MID ) && ( $5 == MNR ) && ( $7 == "status" ) {t=$10} END{print int(t/60)}' /home/ed/start_up_job/my_datum_file.csv`"
```

so when I call my bash script from the terminal `$ ./myscript.txt TMX 098` I get the following output `TMX 098 hours is: 0`
My expected output would be `TMX 098 hours is: 1022.25`

I don't know what is wrong?

Comment: Your `$machine_ID` and `$machine_number` shell variables are not going to get expanded in the awk expression (because of the single-quoting). Instead, look can use `-v` to pass their *values* to awk e.g. `awk -F, -vid="$machine_id" '$4 == id ...'` and so on.

Comment: @steeldriver how do i seperate variable assignments? `awk -F, -vMachine_ID="$machine_ID", -vMachine_Number=$machine_number '($4 == Machine_ID) && ($5 == Machine_number ) && $7 == 'status" {print $10/60}'` is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `cat` that was used from the terminal and with `awk -F, -v MID="$machine_ID" -v MNR="$machine_number" '( $4 == MID ) && ( $5 == MNR ) && ( $7 == "status" ) {t=$10} END{print int(t/60)}' /home/ed/start_up_job/my_datum_file.csv` worked.

Understanding the code:

- `awk -F` defines the field seperator as `,`
- `-v` assigns a value to a program variable
- `MID="$machine_ID"` where as `MID` is the newly given variable name within `awk` for `$machine_ID`, which is a shell variable
- `-v MNR="$machine_number"` similarly `-v` reassigns a `awk` variable called as`MNR` for a shell variable called `$machine_number`
- `( $4 == MID )` equates the `4`th parameter with what `MID` holds
- `&&` and
- `( $5 == MNR )` equates  the `5`th parameter with what `MNR` holds
- `&&` and
- `( $7 == "status" )` equates the `7`th parameter with `status`
- `{t=$10}` assigns the `10`th value to `t`
- `END` is rule that executed, once, after all the input has been read
- `print int(t/60)` print the output of `t/60` *(note no $ sign infront of `t`)* as an `int`eger
- `/home/ed/start_up_job/my_datum_file.csv` from the file in ~

Essentially, in the file `/home/ed/start_up_job/my_datum_file.csv` this bit of code finds the values which hold `MID` and `MNR`. Then the code places  the value of the [$]`10`th parameter to `t` and `print`s it as an `int`eger after `/`ing by `60`